# do-release-upgrade closes with "restoring original system state" on 14.04

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, do-release-upgrade

I'm trying to upgrade from 14.04 LTS to 15.10, but just running do-release-upgrade causes it to fail without an error description and says "restoring original system state." All of my software packages are up to date, and I'm running the latest kernel available to me. Any ideas as to how I can upgrade?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check in `/var/log` for `release-upgrader` log files that will have more details and post the errors in your question.