# Problem upgrading from 16.04 LTS to 18.04 LTS

Tags: 18.04, upgrade, lts

I'm running 16.04 LTS (upstart) on a Dell T5600 computer.  When I tried to upgrade to 18.04 LTS, I got the following:

```
pm@T5600U:~$ sudo do-release-upgrade
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Get:1 Upgrade tool signature [819 B]                                                                                   
Get:2 Upgrade tool [1,246 kB]                                                                                          
Fetched 1,247 kB in 0s (0 B/s)                                                                                         
authenticate 'bionic.tar.gz' against 'bionic.tar.gz.gpg' 
extracting 'bionic.tar.gz'

Reading cache

Checking package manager
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... Done
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease                                                               
Hit http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable InRelease                                                        
Get:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease [109 kB]                                            
Ign http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                                             
Get:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease [107 kB]                                          
Get:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [109 kB]                                             
Hit http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release                                                               
Fetched 325 kB in 0s (0 B/s)                                                                                           
Reading package lists... Done    
Building dependency tree          
Reading state information... Done

Restoring original system state

Aborting
Reading package lists... Done    
Building dependency tree          
Reading state information... Done
pm@T5600U:~$
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: A quick search on the internet indicates that there might be an issue with some packages / ppas. One guy had [issues with a manually installed python packages](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2399060). Check for errors in `/var/log` for `release-upgrader` log files and add them to your question ([via](https://askubuntu.com/questions/728188/do-release-upgrade-closes-with-restoring-original-system-state-on-14-04))

Comment: Go to Software and Updates app→Other Software and disable all third party repositories and try again.